# Serialize everything within a UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I am working on an iPad app to see if I can mimic "screen sharing" between two apps that are nearly identical and running on separate devices. The only difference between the two apps is that one is acting as a server and the other a client, using aSyncSocket.

Basically, I am trying to update the UINavigationController on the server app whenever the UINavigationController on the client app changes by serializing the array returned by the viewControllers property.

I've had some success so far, but I'm having trouble getting any of the subviews (from the array of views) to show up. So once the view is updated on the server app (using setViewControllers), it is missing all the data that is contained within the subviews.

Has anyone worked on something similar? I'm thinking the issue is during the serialization process but I can't pinpoint the issue (or perhaps it's just not possible?). Seems like I'm really close though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two apps are identical, why don't you serialise the user's interactions instead?  Start both apps off in the same state, then any interaction on one, you reproduce on the other.

Comment: This was actually my original approach and it works exactly how I want; however, I found it cumbersome to put in code for each button pressed in all the different views. I'm new to Obj-C/Cocoa so I'm not sure how I can accomplish this without writing specific code for each user interaction.

Comment: If you create a subclass of `UIWindow` and make sure you use that instead of `UIWindow` (using the standard templates, you should only have to change your app delegate's `window` ivar and property and your `MainWindow.xib`), then you can listen for all `UIEvent`s by providing a `sendEvent:` method.  Remember to forward the message on to the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you choose UINavigationController? It seems like the natural thing to do would be to subclass UIWindow, since the window is the view that contains all the views that are currently visible at any given time.

I can see the appeal of serializing all the views and reproducing them on the client, but that might also create a lot of complexity. Not only do you have to pack up and then unpack those views ten or twenty times each second, but you also have two separate apps competing to handle events. What do you do when the user on the client device taps a button? Send it to the server for processing, or process it on the client and then try to reproduce the resulting changes on the server?

Seems like it would be better to send the client an image of the window, and have the client send all events back to the server. I believe this is the way that screen sharing systems usually work, probably for the reasons laid out above.

Comment: Ha the questions you asked are the same questions I'm asking myself. I'm thinking this approach might be too complicated as you said -- though this was just an experiment to begin with.

I really like the idea you mentioned with the server sending an image of the window, I'm going to see about pursuing that option or back to my original one mentioned in Jim's post.